# Dunn pairwise test becomes insignificant between two groups if I add datapoints to the third group

Tags: dunn-test

I am doing pairwise comparisons between 5 groups. The Dunn test with Bonferroni adjustment only came out significant for two groups (say A and B). However, when I added 5 data points to one of the groups (say C), the significant difference between A and B disappeared. total N= 148 (A= 28, B= 43, C= 13). Dunn's calculation does not seem to care to total sample size or overall mean. I do not understand what made the significance disappear.

Comment: It might use some common standard deviation. But in general, trying out many different things until the desired significances pop up is unscientific.

Comment: Dunn's test or better say Dunn's approach for nonparametric pairwise post-hoc testing uses information about all k groups in each comparison, rather than only about the two currently compared

Comment: The z-statistics computation in Dunn does not seem to use common SD. I am not p- fishing and using Dunn for post-hoc comparisons. Reviewers asked to add these 5 data points and significance dissapeared between two groups, though the points were added to the third group. I need some explanation for this behavior. Upon checking Dunn’s computation, I am not able to explain this development. Thus asking the community.

Comment: @ttnphns could you share the reference for this?

Comment: First, define what you mean by the Dunn's test. (What I mean is the post-hoc pairwise comparison after Kruskal-Wallis.)

Comment: Thanks for correction. I mean the same. Posthoc pairwise comparison after Kruskal-Wallis.

Comment: Then, please get the formula of the test. You'll see that information from all k groups is utilized in each pair compared